# Unable to extract data from XML file using javascript in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, xml

The following code works fine in firefox but as with many other things, I cant get it working in Internet explorer (any version).

Can anybody help?

```
<body>
   <script type="text/javascript">
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
            {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
            }
        else
            {// code for IE6, IE5
                xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
        xmlhttp.open("GET","messages.xml",false);
        xmlhttp.send();
        xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML;

        var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("entry");
        for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
            {
                document.write("<b>From:</b> ");
                document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("username")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
                document.write("<br />");
                document.write("<b>Date:</b> ");
                document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("date")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
                document.write("<br />");
                document.write("<b>Message:</b> ");
                document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("message")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
                document.write("<br />");
                document.write("<br />");

            }
    </script>

</body>
```

Comment: Please post the error that you're getting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two potential issues spring to mind:

1. Perhaps your AJAX communication is failing. In which case I would strongly urge you to use a library like [JQuery](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/) to handle your communication. Then you don't have to worry about the browser compatibility issues
2. Secondly, the data coming back from the server is not sent with `content-type("application/xml")`. Different browsers may behave differently if they cannot reliably detect the content type and know that it's XML that you're expecting.

**[Edit]**

This is a full working example that I tested in IE7

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
 <head>
   <title></title>
 </head>
 <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
         if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
             {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                 xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
             }
         else
             {// code for IE6, IE5
                 xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
             }
         xmlhttp.open("GET","messages.xml",false);
         xmlhttp.send();
         xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML;

         var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("entry");
         for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
             {
                 document.write("<b>From:</b> ");
                 document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("username")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
                 document.write("<br />");
                 document.write("<b>Date:</b> ");
                 document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("date")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
                 document.write("<br />");
                 document.write("<b>Message:</b> ");
                 document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("message")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
                 document.write("<br />");
                 document.write("<br />");

             }
     </script>

     <div>Hi</div>

</body>
</html>
```

And the test data from `messages.xml` also located at the root of my server

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
    <entry>
        <username>A</username>
        <date>B</date>
        <message>C</message>
    </entry>
</root>
```

This produces the following output

```
From: A
Date: B
Message: C

Hi
```

IE is a pain to debug because it has very limited debugging tools. I checked with FireFox's FireBug add-on to see that the content-type from my WAMP server was "application/xml".

[image: content-type=application/xml]

You should also make sure that your XML document is valid by running it through a validator.

Comment: I feel really stupid, at your mention of your WAMP server. I tried running it on my local server.... You guessed it - all working on IE now.